# Starting lodash map from index 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash, slice

I am currently using [lodash map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) to map over an array of objects.

I always need index 0 in the array to do something different. 
Is there a way to make map start at index 1, without mutating or messing with the array?

I know that I can use [slice(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Just wondering if there was another way to start from index 1 rather than 0. So I didn't have to join them back together afterwards.

Comment: A word of advice - if the data structure is inconsistent - even with just one item - and you are operating on the entire structure as a whole, it shouldn't be part of the data. You should strive to avoid this behaviour, since it will most likely add complications later on. Consider removing your first element and using it elsewhere, rather than avoiding it.

Comment: You can just use `yourData.slice(1)` and work from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second parameter of [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) accepts a function which has 3 arguments `(value, index|key, collection)`.
So you can skip the first value using `index` and play with the rest of your data using `value`.

Something like this:

```js
let data = [0, 1, 2];

let result = _.map(data, (value, index) => {
  if (index === 0) {
    return value;
  } else {
    return value * 2;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```